# unsupported devices on Google Play Console - Nasoni D'italia

Tags: android, android-manifest

I do not understand why there are some devices not supported..

this is my manifest..
i think the problem depends from minsdk or targetsdk or screen resolution but i don't know where is the problem. 
Generally devices unsupported have small screen resolution.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.ankic.nasone"

    android:minSdkVersion="11"
//----------------------------------------

 >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    //-------------------------------------//
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
//----------------------------------------//
                                     <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="nasone"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyDaRR2jB_mVyoDe31KFfjXyBiobfGq6sbc"/>
    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="it.ankic.nasone.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="it.ankic.nasone.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:minSdkVersion="11" 
android:targetSdkVerion="17"

<supports-screens
    android:SmallScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Android Sdk Version tags will check the device os sdk version . and also it will check the permissions for screen supports. four types of screen supports is there. if u release the App in Google play means , then it check the android manifest and device configuaration if it,s ok then only the app will display for thaT Mobile.

Also Users Features tag will affect the App supportabily to Device.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this:

```
 <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
```

because Google Play filter device which support this uses-feature. If the device does not support your glEsversion, Google Play does not propose it on the store.
Try to remove it and give me a feedback.